# Multiple command with docker-compose in a Makefile

Tags: docker, makefile, docker-compose

I have a **Makefile** calling **docker-compose** to run commands in containers.
It looks like this:

```
COMPOSE=docker-compose
PHP=$(COMPOSE) run --rm -u `id -u`:`id -g` -T php

.SILENT:
.PHONY: help

install-dependencies:
    $(PHP) php composer config --global disable-tls true
    $(PHP) php composer config --global secure-http false
    $(PHP) curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer > composer-setup.php
    $(PHP) php composer-setup.php
    $(PHP) php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"
    $(PHP) php composer.phar install --ignore-platform-reqs
```

The problem is that for each line, it is launching the PHP docker image.
Would it be possible to run the same list of commands using only one docker-compose inside the Makefile?
For example, something like this:

```
COMPOSE=docker-compose
PHP=$(COMPOSE) run --rm -u `id -u`:`id -g` -T php

.SILENT:
.PHONY: help

install-dependencies:
    $(PHP) php composer config --global disable-tls true |
      php composer config --global secure-http false |
      curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer > composer-setup.php |
      php composer-setup.php |
      php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');" |
      php composer.phar install --ignore-platform-reqs
```

Thanks !

Comment: This seems like you want to write these commands into a Dockerfile, that you can `docker build` into a reusable image.  Docker has a [Sample application](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/02_our_app/) tutorial that walks through that process.

Comment: No, I need to run this commands through a Makefile as I need to be able to call them from a shell. The provided commands are just an example.